# How to get old value of a field using vue inside blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am having a registration form that uses vue inside Laravel blade file. I'm using a validator for invalid inputs of user and I want to get the old value of the field but now I can't make it work since some of the fields are using vue. Here's my code:

**regist.blade.php**

```
<div class="regist_input">
      <input type="email" name="email" v-model="email" v-bind:placeholder="placeholder_email" v-bind:class="{ error: emailError }">
      <p class="error_text" v-bind:class="{ active: emailError2 }">Invalid email.</p>
      @if($errors->has('email'))
          <p class="alert-error">
          {{ $errors->first('email') }}
          </p>
      @endif
</div>
<dd>
    <div class="regist_input">
        <input class="input_company" type="text" name="company" value="{{ old('company') }}" placeholder="company"> //this one works
    </div>
</dd>
```

**controller**

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->errors());
}
```

I can display its old value if out side the field, which means that my php function that validates is working.

I tried using `v-bind:value="{{ old('email') }}"` or `:value="{{ old('email') }}"` but is not working.For this one, how can I display the old value in the input field that has a vue component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass the blade `email` data to vue using [data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

First should add an id to an HTML element with data attribute on it. Then use blade to parse your data and set the data attribute to `email` data.

```
<div id="email-data" data-email="{{ old('email') }}"></div>
```

**TO BE EXACT (OP)**

```
<input type="email"  value="{{ old('email') }}" name="email" v-model="email" id="email-data" data-email="{{ old('email') }}" v-bind:placeholder="placeholder_email"
    v-bind:class="{ error: emailError }">
```

Then in the created / mounted hook in vue extract the data and set to the `email` state.

```
created() {
    const el = document.getElementById('email-data')
    const email = el.dataset.email
    this.email = email
}
```

Comment: Should I change something on this part of my code `<input type="email" name="email" v-model="email" v-bind:placeholder="placeholder_email" v-bind:class="{ error: emailError }">` ?

Answer (score -1):

`v-bind:value="{{ old('email') }}"` or `:value="{{ old('email') }}` don't work because you are using `v-model="email"`

When you use v-model, it means that there should be an "email" property in the "data" attribute of a Vue component, and any value set to that "email" property will be what is displayed as the value of the input field.

[See this Pen](https://codepen.io/jaireina/pen/mgmeBM) I created to illustrate both scenarios.

So, you'll need to remove the v-model if you want to use the v-bind:value. And now that I'm writing this, I don't think you need the v-bind:value and can just simply use value (just as you're doing with the company input.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but the problem is when I clicked the submit button and the validator fails, old value are gone. How can I retain  it? Please see my update with my controller.